# How to show particular textblock on button click in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, textblock

i am working on an application using C# WPF and MVVM.The problem i want to show summary on button click event in textblocks and textblocks are inside ListBox as follows:

```
 <ListBox>
           <TextBlock
               TextWrapping="Wrap"
               Height="350"
               Text="{Binding ShowVlan}"
            </TextBlock>
          <TextBlock
               TextWrapping="Wrap"
               Height="350"
               Text="{Binding ShowRouting}">
               </TextBlock>
    </ListBox>
```

I have two buttons and i want that if i click 1st button then 1st textblock should be display and on second button click i want to display second textblock .It is working now but the actual problem is that i want to display to on same positions but these are displaying one after another .I am also attaching screenshot for better understanding.

Comment: Do you actually need a listBox? You can have both TextBlock in a grid(in the same row/column) and add visibility triggers on them.

Comment: I don't see the need for a ListBox in such situation !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply put both `TextBlock` at the same Grid Cell and set their Visibility to true/False based on the selected Button :

```
<TextBlock x:Name="ShowVlanTb" Visibility="Hidden"
               TextWrapping="Wrap"
               Height="350"
               Text="{Binding ShowVlan}" Grid.Row=1 Grid.Colomn=2
            />
          <TextBlock x:Name="ShowRoutingTb" Visibility="Hidden"
               TextWrapping="Wrap"
               Height="350"
               Text="{Binding ShowRouting}" Grid.Row=1 Grid.Colomn=2>
               />
```

and on the button Click event handler set the Visiblity to Visible:

```
ShowVlanTb.Visibility=Visibility.Visible 
ShowRoutingTb.Visibility=Visibility.Hidden
```